# schedule background job after save object in parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have the following logic and want to implement it using parse

1) add feed object with schedule time
2) after save object --> schedule a background job that will run on feed schedule time
3) when the feed schedule time come use parse installation to send push notification with feed data to user

My code is as following :

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Feed", function(request) {

// schedule background job here 

});

// this is the code of my cloud job

Parse.Cloud.job("schedulePush", function(request, status) {

  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  var message = {"message" : "Hello world!"}
  query.each(function(installation) {

      Parse.Push.send({
            where:query,
                data: {
                    "notification_info": {"message" : "hello world!"} 
                },
                }
            ).then(function() {
                console.log("Push was sent successfully | " + message)
            }, function(error) {
                response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
            });

  }).then(function() {
    status.success("schedulePush completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong." + error.message);
  });
});
```

Comment: I think is not possible, I've never seen this feature in the doc. You can put your code schedulePush in your afterSave function.

Answer (score 1):

First, change

`Parse.Cloud.job("schedulePush", function(request, status) {`

to

`Parse.Cloud.define("schedulePush", function(request, response) {`

because it can be a regular function (with a 15-second timeout, mind you). This also means changing `status.success` and `status.error` to `response.success` and `response.error`.

Second, you top function needs to be:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Feed", function(request) {

   // schedule background job here 
   Parse.Cloud.run("schedulePush", function(request, response) {
       // handle response here
   });

});
```

I typed this without being able to run it, so I may be off on a syntactical point or two. But this gives you an idea of what you need to do.